# Cypress intercept 404 when trying to get local json file

Tags: angular, unit-testing, cypress, cypress-intercept

I'm writing a component test in Cypress for an Angular app. This component on init reads a local json file using a GET like this (this.http is the HttpClient instance):

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.http
        .get<LibraryDynamicData[]>('assets/libraries.json')
        .pipe(take(1))
        .subscribe(...);
}
```

In the test I tried to stub this call using `cy.intercept` with no result. This is what I have

```
it('should get libraries data', () => {
    cy.intercept('assets/libraries.json', []).as('libraries');

    cy.mount(AppComponent, { imports: [AppModule] }).then(() => {
        cy.wait('@libraries').then(interception => {
            assert.isNotNull(interception.response.body, 'Data received');
            ...
        });
    });
});
```

I get the following error as if Cypress didn't intercept the request.

[image: Cypress error]

I also tried to change the url using wildcards like `**/libraries.json` with no success. What am I doing wrong and how can I stub that call?

Answer (score -1):

To stub a json body you will have to do like so:

```
cy.intercept('/projects', {
  body: [],
}).as('libraries');
```

Check also [the docs here on how to stub a static response](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#With-a-StaticResponse-object).